# Why is routing to 'name' not working when it works for 'id'?

Tags: node.js, express, postman, node-mysql

I have local backend on mysql and I am using connect Node.js to connect both of them. Everything is working fine. The connection is succesfull all the queries are happening but why is this not working.

```
router.get("/:users/:name", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  console.log(req.params);
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?",
    [name],
    (error, rows, fields) => {
      console.log(rows);
      console.log(error);
      if (!error) {
        res.json(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

whereas it's counterpart is working.

```
router.get("/:users/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  mysqlConnection.query(
    "select * from user where id = ?",
    [id],
    (error, rows, fields) => {
      if (!error) {
        res.json(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

I am using Postman to test my routes.
eg: localhost:8080\users\name

I have tried this

```
router.get("/:users/:name", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  console.log(req.params);
  mysqlConnection.query(
    `SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '${name}'`,
    (error, rows, fields) => {
      console.log(rows);
      console.log(error);
      if (!error) {
        res.json(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: If you need more information please do tell

Comment: MySQL is a database. This looks like [tag:express]

Comment: You need to describe what you mean by your app not working! We have absolutely no clue what your app is supposed to be doing and what's happening instead.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to have `:users` as a route parameter?

Comment: It should connects to the database and fetches all the users with the same name using router.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Express cannot differentiate between `:id` and `:name`; they're both just single string parameters so any matching request will be routed to whatever one is registered first.

Assuming that `id` is numeric, you can provide more matching information so Express knows where to route requests like `/users/123`

```js
// register the more specific route first
router.get("/users/:id(\\d+)", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  // etc...
});

// register the more general route second
router.get("/users/:name", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;

  // etc...
});
```

See [Route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

Comment: I just checked the problem is in the order they are occurring inside the file. I just changed the code by putting the `:name` on top and now it is working but not the `:id` one

Comment: No, you definitely want the `id` route with the regex validation defined first